# what does "Net user administrator /active:yes" do to a computer?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, administration

i just purchased a new laptop and had some issues with it... I called tech support and they had me run this command in cmd prompt by right clicking the cmd icon and selecting "run as administrator" with root C:\windows\system32>:

"Net user administrator /active:no"

after it was determined that it didn't fix the issue we ran this code

"Net user administrator /active:yes"

i then rebooted..and was asked for my windows login for my user account "Rees" as usual.. however ALL my settings where gone (including my desktop files) as though it was the first time I booted up.

WHAT in the world happened with this command?? I desperately NEED my user accounts and files back to how they were!! (running windows 7) Please help!

Comment: What folders are there in `C:\Users`?

Answer (score 4):

I was under the impression that it enables the built-in hidden Administrator account.

Comment: `administrator` can be replaced with any disabled user account.

Answer (score 1):

That command by itself could not have erased your user profile.  As Matt said, all that does is enable/disable the Administrator account.

Check `C:\Users` to see if you have two profile directories in there.  Sometimes a second profile will get created (for example, `Rees` and `Rees.COMPUTERNAME` might co-exist).  If there's only one directory there that looks like it's your profile, then something else must have happened to wipe it out; see if there are any more details of what the tech had you do that might be helpful here.

If you do have two profile folders, there are a few options.  First, you could just manually copy the files you need from the old profile to the new one.  This is the simplest, but depending on how much data you have it could become time-consuming.

Second, you could rename your old profile folder to the new name.  This will get your whole profile back, but some programs which have saved hard-coded paths (`C:\Users\Rees\Whatever`) might get confused.

Third, you can modify the registry to point your user profile back to the old location.  Instructions for doing this can be found [here](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/userpath.htm) and [here](http://www.neotitans.com/resources/windows/changing-user-profiles-directory.html), but be careful because you could mess up your user account even more if you make a mistake.